# Abstract class implemented by 2 activity work improperly

Tags: android, kotlin

1. Home activity
2. GeneralPlayer activity

I make 2 activity with extends abstract class which contain an abstract method. abstract method has a different implementation in all 2 class.

when app starts it will go home activity and call its method which declared abstract in abstract class. it's fine.

when I will go to second(GeneralPlayer) activity. then its abstract method call .which is also fine but when I came to home activity than here GeneralPlayer activity abstract method call which is wrong. Here home activity abstract method implementation should call..

look at code

```
abstract class PlayerAbstractClass() : AppCompatActivity() {
      protected fun initiliseUIHandler(){
        Constants.PLAYER_UI = Handler(object : Handler.Callback {
            override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?): Boolean {
                updateButtonUI()
                return true
            }
        })
     }
     protected abstract fun updateButtonUI()
}

class GeneralPlayer : PlayerAbstractClass() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        initiliseUIHandler()
    }

    override fun updateButtonUI() {
      Log.i("MusicPlayer","activity")
  }
}

class Home : PlayerAbstractClass(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        initiliseUIHandler()
    }

   override fun updateButtonUI() {
      Log.i("HOME","activity")
   }
}
```

So when app start Home activity call it print **HOME: activity**
when i went to GeneralPlayer it print **MusicPlayer: activity**

Above both statement are fine.
but when i came back again on home activity then it call **MusicPlayer:activity** which is wrong it should call **HOME:activity**

Can please tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: How do you go back to home activity ? With the "back" button of your device ? Via a button in the app ?

Comment: please show us all code

Comment: I just updated my code i think it may help

Comment: I pressed device back button to go back on home activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `Constants.PLAYER_UI` to the `Handler` of the most recently created Activity. So here is what is happening:

- You create `Home`, it creates the `Constants.PLAYER_UI` `Handler` with a reference to `Home`, which then calls the right method.
- You then go to `GeneralPlayer`. This resets the `Constants.PLAYER_UI` `Handler` with the `GeneralPlayer` created `Handler`. This holds a reference to `GeneralPlayer`, so it calls the right method.
- You go back to `Home`. However, `onCreate()` isn't called, as `Home` has already been created. So `Constants.PLAYER_UI` **is still referencing the Handler created by GeneralPlayer**. So when that method is called (from somewhere else I would assume), it's using the `GeneralPlayer` activity that it held a reference to, and outputs the `GeneralPlayer` message.

Do you need the `Handler` to be a constant? You can have it just be a instance variable on the activity, so that a new instance gets created with every activity and destroyed alongside it as well:

```
abstract class PlayerAbstractClass() : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val playerUiHandler = Handler(object : Handler.Callback {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?): Boolean {
            updateButtonUI()
            return true
        }
    })

    protected abstract fun updateButtonUI()
}
```

That way your `Home` activity has its own `playerUiHandler` instance which it will call every time you're on `Home`, and similarly `GeneralPlayer` will have a different `playerUiHandler` instance that gets called when you're on that activity. As an added bonus, you are no longer leaking the `Context` and holding references to activities that should have been destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, bro. I know home activity onCreate() not called when i go back again. but I forgot to re-initialise handler. I forgot that handler still referencing the Handler created by GeneralPlayer. thanks again...